# constructor in javascript using new String ()

Tags: javascript

```
a = new String("av");
a.constructor == String /* line no 2 */
```

My question is why there is no double quotes with String in line no 2

Comment: @void It is not a duplicate ,remove the tag.

Comment: I can see that you have edited your question. Earlier it was the duplicate!

Comment: `a.constructor` prints `[Function: String]`,  so you are comparing the constructor to the data type **String** not to string itself

Comment: @akhilesh if (typeof a=="object") then why here we are enclosing object in double quotes.

Comment: You are comparing two references, which are both equal.

Answer (score 0):

> The typeof operator is used to get the data type (returns a string) of its operand. The operand can be either a literal or a data structure such as a variable, a function, or an object. The operator returns the data type. [Reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```
$ var c = "asdasd";
$ typeof c
'string'
```

> But every constructor property point to the constructor function that created it, in this case a **String()** [Reference link](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-javascript-constructors/)

```
$ a.constructor
[Function: String]
```